# Solr 4.2 admin main page only shows 'loading ...'

Tags: solr, admin, solr4

I jus installed Solr 4.2 on my local computer using port 8080 and test ok with url  `http://localhost : 8080/solr/`, then I share this to my colleagues with url `http://10.18.59.179:8080/solr/` where 10.18.59.179 is local ip of my company. However my colleague (his ip is 10.18.59.105) told me, the admin main page just shows 'loading...' and hang there. I've installed solr 3.3 before and they can connect to admin page on my computer correctly. What's wrong with Solr 4.2's admin page?

Comment: There should me something about access rights to your machine. Does your friend can ping to your computer? What OS do you use? Maybe some issues about iptables?

Comment: Solved! You guess right!  Thanks!

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer.

Comment: I have observed that using the IP address instead of host name "fixes" (or at least avoids) the problem in some cases.  I see that this did not seem to avoid the problem that the original poster described.  But it worked for me.  (So I think we need to fix our DNS entries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr 4.2 code is a tested and working stable release. If you can reach its admin page but someone else can not reach it, the first thing to check it does another machine has right to reach your computer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, any browser will show 'loading...' forever. The reason, again in my case, is I started Solr 5.2 with a typo in ZooKeeper switch. It should be "-z localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183" but I had "-z localhost:2181,localhost2182,localhost:2183". After adding the ":", everything started working again.